# VbScript FormateDateTime function showing different format for two files

Tags: vbscript

I have got below code, where I am sending the formatted date and time to my XSLT and which is giving a XML as output.

```
#importXSLT "tcm:228-190529-2048" As expandXSLT
#importXSLT "tcm:228-642694-2048" As renderXSLT

Dim xml, currentDateTime, datLong , datLongTime , fullDate

Set xml = getNewDomDocument()
xml.loadXML TDSE.GetListPublications(3)

expandXSLT.input = xml
Call expandXSLT.addParameter("publication", Component.Publication.Id)
expandXSLT.transform

xml.loadXML(expandXSLT.output)
'WriteOut xml.xml

currentDateTime = now()
datLong = FormatDateTime(currentDateTime, 1)
datLongTime = FormatDateTime(currentDateTime, 3)
fullDate = datLong &" "& datLongTime

renderXSLT.input = xml
Call renderXSLT.addParameter("currentPublishedDate", CStr(fullDate))
renderXSLT.transform

WriteOut renderXSLT.output

Set xml = Nothing
```

Now above logic for doing date formatting is same for two outputted XML, but suprising I am getting different output for both the files.

First File gives - Sunday, October 23, 2011 8:52:36 AM as output
Second File gives - 23 October 2011 09:14:45 as output.

Please suggest what can be reason as well as solution also, and one more thing if I want output as below for both the file  as **23 October 2011 09:14:45 AM**

Thanks!!

Comment: what environment are you running this in?

Comment: Its Windows 7 Enterprise..please what you are looking?

Comment: i meant is this in ASP, Windows Script Host, Internet Explorer etc?

Comment: Its ASP, IE7...please let me know if anything more required?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Before you do the date formatting, try to explicitly set the locale using something like `SetLocale(2057)`.

2057 is UK format which seems to be what you want, otherwise look at this [Locale ID Chart](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0h88fahh%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) to find the correct value.